# Discrete Math Sequences (Graph or No Graph)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Determine if there exists a graph whose degree sequence is the one specified. Draw a graph, or explain why no graph exists. The sequence is 5,4,3,2,1,1

Answer (score 2):

The graph doesn't exist since you need the vertex of degree 5 to be connected to all the others (in particular both vertices of degree 1 already have their single neighbor).

Now the vertex of degree 4 must be connected to 3 of the vertices with the following degrees: 3,2,1,1. In particular it must be connected to a vertex of degree 1. This is a contradiction since this vertex is already connected to the vertex of degree 5.

EDIT:

Another way to look at this would be to "distribute" the degrees of the vertices (this is just deleting edges):

Start with

$$5,4,3,2,1,1$$

Distribute the $5$:

$$0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0$$

Distributing the $3$ gives:

$$0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0$$

or

$$0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1$$

You now have unavoidably hit vertices of negative degree. Which is impossible.

Comment: I kind of see what you are saying, but am still confused. Could you possibly go into a little more detail? I missed this class, and am pretty lost with this whole topic, and this is the only review problem they gave us....

Comment: The vertex of degree 5 is connected to all the other vertices. This means that the vertices of degree 1 can't connect to anything else, or they would have a larger degree.

Comment: The vertex of degree 4 must also be connected to a vertex of degree 1, but this can't happen by my previous comment. @JebusCrust

Comment: Oh Thank you! That makes sense to me!

Comment: @JebusCrust I also added another explanation which may be easier to follow. It involves deleting the edges you know exist.

Comment: That made it even easier to look at. Makes perfect sense, thank you!